# returning object attributes in get request in a better way

Tags: rest, api, flask

Learning the basics of Flask development and it just seems as though I am missing something in order to return all of the attributes of an object.

```
@app.route("/teams/<int:idtofind>", methods=['GET'])
def findbyID(idtofind=None):
    for i in teamlist:
        if i.id == idtofind:
            return i.__dict__
```

I expect to either return a dictionary of the values, which this code does, but I feel as thought the **dict** is suboptimal.

{
    "abbrev": "CLE",
    "city": "Cleveland",
    "full_name": "Cleveland Cavaliers",
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Cavaliers"
}

Comment: Your code seems good. what do you mean by 'missing something in order to return all the attributes of an object'?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you wanted only the attributes of the dictionary object.

```
@app.route('/teams/<int:idtofind>', methods=['GET'])
def findbyID(idtofind=None):
  global teamlist
  for i in teamlist:
    if i.id == idtofind:            
      return ', '.join(i.__dict__.keys())
  return ''
```